# Customize the "Available for back order" text for specific variation

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, jquery

In Woocommerce, on the product page, i want to customize the "Available for back order" text for specific variations (size L and XL). So when a customer selects size L or XL, the "Available for back order" text will show "Custom Made to Measure". I know how to change the text, but how do i do it only for size L and XL? Thank you!

```
function change_backorder_message( $text, $product ){
    if ( $product->managing_stock() && $product->is_on_backorder( 1 ) ) {
        $text = __( 'Custom Made to Measure ', 'your-textdomain' );
    }
    return $text;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'change_backorder_message', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it.

The "stock.available-on-backorder.step-1" is the css class of the availability text ( Available- made to measure

).

```
<?php 
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity', 'made_to_measure' );

function made_to_measure() {

   global $product;

   if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {

      ?>
      <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

         $('input.variation_id').change( function(){
            if( '' != $('input.variation_id').val() ) {

               //var var_id = $('input.variation_id').val();
               var pa_size = jQuery( "#pa_size" ).val();
               if (pa_size=='l' || pa_size=='xl')
               {
                $('.stock.available-on-backorder.step-1').html("Available- made to measure");

               }


            }
         });
```